# Ubuntu-specific programming questions are on-topic, so let's reopen this one

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, closed-questions, answered-questions

This (somewhat confusingly named question) question was closed, perhaps because it is asking something about programming. (It is, and has never been, in any way about Microsoft Windows. It's about the Unity Spread.)

- [How do I access the windows spread programmatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190660/how-do-i-access-the-windows-spread-programmatically)

[As Jorge Castro pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190660/how-do-i-access-the-windows-spread-programmatically#comment236516_190670), programming questions that are specific to Ubuntu are considered on-topic for Ask Ubuntu:

> Your question is ontopic here, as it's related to developing on Ubuntu the platform, it's in the FAQ.

Jorge Castro is quite right--[the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) says:

> We welcome questions about:
>
> . . .
>
> - Development on Ubuntu.

This question has a pretty good answer, and if we reopen it, it might get some more good answers too.

**So let's reopen [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190660/how-do-i-access-the-windows-spread-programmatically).** (Two more reopen votes needed, at this time.)

---

As an aside, please note that programming is somewhat special, in that *most of the time* programming questions must be *specifically* about Ubuntu (or particularly important to Ubuntu developers) to be on-topic.

By that standard, the question at issue here definitely qualifies as on-topic.

What makes programming special is that most questions **do not have to be Ubuntu-specific at all to be on topic**. I've noticed that, especially since the new review system has been put in place, several on-topic questions that *are* about Ubuntu have been erroneously closed, because they also applied to one or more non-Ubuntu OSes. **What matters is if the question *is about Ubuntu*.**

So, for example:

- A question about how to clear a terminal screen in `bash` would be on-topic for Ask Ubuntu, even though it would also apply to some other non-Ubuntu environments that have `bash`, like Fedora, Solaris, Haiku, and Cygwin.
- A question about how to use the Synaptic Package Manager would be on-topic, as Synaptic is available for Ubuntu, even though it is also available in some other OSes (like Debian) and is no longer Ubuntu's default package manager.

  - A question about how to use Synaptic in some other OS, or answers particular to a non-Ubuntu OS, would of course be off-topic, however.

Comment: I can't cast more than one reopen vote. :|

Comment: I would suggest that [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59597/are-there-any-good-mongodb-gui-clients) should also be reopened, for the same reason. And a good reason to think so is because I found it looking for the same thing, and I looked here first (I later found the answer on Stack Overflow)

Comment: @Eyal I've [commented](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59597/are-there-any-good-mongodb-gui-clients#comment243876_59597) about that. Please also see fossfreedom's earlier comment. If it doesn't get reopened soon or you want to discuss it further, I recommend [posting a new meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I would suggest Eyal create a new question (or similar) and immediately post an answer that he can accept.  If necessary I can then dupe or merge the questions.  The reason for this is because the OP is question seldom visits the site and as such may not "accept" the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: [Here's the new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196136/what-is-a-good-mongodb-gui-client).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Done, It is now reopened

I casted 5th reopen vote

Comment: Thanks for the reopen vote!